# How to implement the New Android 11 Double Tap Back Gesture, on Flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, accessibility

I would like to use the the new android 11 double tap back gesture, on my app which I'm working on. I got this idea from an app Tap, Tap [Github Repository](https://github.com/KieronQuinn/TapTap). I tried to find some related package in https://pub.dev, but I guess I couldn't get the right keyword to find it.

Any Help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit:** After some research, I found that this android 11 feature is available under accessibility, so maybe it available in flutter accessibility widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally, figured it out. We can use the **gyro sensor** and **accelerometer** to achieve the same result, but I guess it will be less accurate. Further more we all also use Machine Learning to  increase the accuracy of the double tap feature.

Hope this answer will help my curious fellow developers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this dependency library to you, it supports the following functions and is simple and lightweight

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_close_app

- ✅ Press back 2 times to close app

  - ✅ Custom time interval
  - ✅ Customize the prompt message
  - ✅ Customize matching conditions
  - ✅ Support Android
- ✅ One click to close app

  - ✅ Support iOS
  - ✅ Support MacOS
  - ✅ Support Windows
  - ✅ Support Linux